# Lebesgue number lemma application

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am reading the proof in which I am supposed to use Lebesgue number lemma.

Now, I know the general notion of this lemma, which is:

If the metric space $(X,d)$ is compact and an open cover of $X$ is given, then there exists a number $\delta >0$ such that every subset of $X$ having diameter less than $\delta$ is contained in some member of the cover.

I am working with interval $[0,1]$ and the author claims that

"...by the Lebesgue-number lemma, we can
partition $[0, 1]$ into intervals

{$[0, s_1], [s_1, s_2], . . . , [s_k, 1]$} such that each
sub-interval $[s_q, s_{q+1}]$ is contained in some member of the cover."

What I don't get is how exactly one can apply this lemma to get these subintervals?

Comment: You are given some open cover of $[0,1]$, say, $\bigcup U_{\alpha}=[0,1]$ where
$U_\alpha$ are open in $[0,1]$. The lemma gives you a Lebesgue number $\lambda>0$ for this open cover. So you choose your invervals $[s_q,s_{q+1}]$ in such a way that $s_{q+1}-s_q<\lambda$, so that the lemma ensures that each of these intervals, being a set of diameter less than $\lambda$, is contained in some $U_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking at first. But what confuses me further is, what can guarantee that there is only finitely many these $s_i$'s. @uniquesolution

Comment: Can't you see that about $1/\lambda$ many intervals are sufficient to cover $[0,1]$?